# django oscar and djangocms

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-oscar

I am interested in combining [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org) for content management and [django oscar](http://oscarcommerce.com/) for e-commerce.

Can someone give me some direction, preferably someone that has already successfully combined the two:

[A] Should the structure be a base oscar site, with the oscar templates modified to insert the necessary placeholders to permit cms etc...,

**OR**

[B] Should the structure be a base django-cms site, with oscar being handled by plugins etc...

My gut feeling is that it should be [A], but please correct me if I am wrong.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated, as there is little online, and I have written to the author of oscar with no response. I am aware of [THIS](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/wiki/CMS-comparison) link, which doesn't address implementation, only comparing compatibilities.

Comment: Anybody tried to do integration of Django-Oscar 2.0 with Django-Cms 3.6.0 and Django 2.1 ? I took djangocms-oscar apphook and tried to upgrade to path() instead of url() but nothing works.

I get 'catalogue' is not a registered namespace error.

I will post code snippets later if required but I'd like to know if somebody did it and have a working project.

Answer (score 2):

This combination is something that I've been looking at for a while and actually had a working prototype. Without knowing your full use case it's difficult to advise properly.

What I required sounds very similar to you, a site that can have CMS editable pages on the same sub domain (e.g. www.myshop.uk/shop www.myshop.uk/cms-pages) as the oscar provided pages. I wanted to have the initial homepage driven by the CMS and a separate area of the site for the E-commerce pages.

If your requirements are the same as mine, the best way to achieve the integration is via an app hook in Django CMS, this would mean that the CMS is the controlling package: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/apphooks.html

I used the following documentation, the code didn't work on more recent versions of Oscar and CMS but was a good guide of what should be possible and a push in the right direction: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-oscar/0.1

I will be attempting this again very soon as I have a new site where the CMS and E-commerce site are separate and need merging under the same sub domain.

Is this still an issue for you?

I am considering either contacting the author about updating the previous project "djangocms-oscar" or creating a new one with supporting docs for others.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the very similar configuration you have asked here. A pure blend of `django-cms` with `django-oscar`.

Here's what I did and it works perfectly fine.

First setup a new project with [cookiecutter-django-cms](https://github.com/palazzem/cookiecutter-django-cms)

Then install django-oscar inside it.
Setup your shop.

As long as I know, it works fine.